# jquery replace element to a new element with its own text

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jquery and just messing around trying to learn.
I'm trying to change all my < p> elements into < button> elements, with the same text as their corresponding p element.

So if I had this html:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Here is a paragraph</p>
<p>And Another</p>
```

I want to change it to this:

```
<button>Hello</button>
<button>Here is a paragraph</button>
<button>And Another</button>
```

However, my jquery code is selecting all < p> elements' text at the same time so I get this:

```
<button>Hello Here is a paragraph And Another</button>
<button>Hello Here is a paragraph And Another</button>
<button>Hello Here is a paragraph And Another</button>
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my jquery/javascript:

```
var ChangeToButton = function () {
    $("p").replaceWith ("<button>" + $("this").text() + "</button>");
}

$("button").on("click", function (event) {
    ChangeToButton();
});
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: `$("p").replaceWith (function(){return "<button>" + this.innerHTML + "</button>"});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the receiver function of [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function),

```
$("p").replaceWith (function(_,content){ 
    return "<button>" + content + "</button>" 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qNL9/)